# c# IndexOf string search

Tags: c#

I have this code working but its using IndexOf I am not sure if that is the best or only option for search for a string value. What I have is a list that will need to remove a world from the child name if it is the same as the name.

> Is this the best way to complete this task?

```
namespace DupName
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder sbchildName = new StringBuilder();

            List<Item> items = new List<Item>()
            .AddAlso(new Item { Id = 1, Name = "Audi", ChildName = "Audi A3 Premium Plus" })
            .AddAlso(new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Audi", ChildName = "Audi A5 Premium Plus" })
            .AddAlso(new Item { Id = 1, Name = "Audi", ChildName = "Audi A6 Premium Plus 55 TFSI quattro" })
            .AddAlso(new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Audi", ChildName = "S5 Premium Plus 3.0 TFSI quattro" })
            .AddAlso(new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Audi", ChildName = "S3 Premium Plus 3.0 TFSI quattro" });

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item.ChildName.IndexOf(item.Name) != -1)
            {
                string temp = string.Format("{0} {1}", item.ChildName.Replace(item.Name, ""), "Car");
                Console.WriteLine(temp.Trim());
                childName.AppendFormat(temp.Trim());
            }
            else
            {
                string temp = string.Format("{0} {1}", item.ChildName, "Car");
                Console.WriteLine(temp.Trim());
                childName.AppendFormat(temp.Trim());
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static List<T> AddAlso<T>(this List<T> list, T item)
        {
            list.Add(item);
            return list;
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ChildName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

output:

```
A3 Premium Plus Car
A5 Premium Plus Car
A6 Premium Plus 55 TFSI quattro Car
S5 Premium Plus 3.0 TFSI quattro Car
S3 Premium Plus 3.0 TFSI quattro Car
```

Comment: Please add some unit tests to your code, to demonstrate that it works as intended. To me, the code looks broken.

Comment: Why have you written an extension for something that's built into `List<T>` already: https://www.dotnetperls.com/initialize-list ? `childName` is appended to and then... nothing happens? If `item.ChildName` doesn't contain `item.Name` you don't dpo anything with `item.ChildName` in `childName.AppendFormat`. Why is `"Audi"` hardcoded in `childName.AppendFormat`? Is this even real code? Your code doesn't even do what you say it does: "a list that will need to remove a word from the child name".

Comment: if item.ChildName.IndexOf(item.Name) != -1 then I just set sbchildName = item.ChildName

Comment: What if they produce a `Quattro Audible edition` someday?

Comment: @RolandIllig not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no reason why you use `IndexOf()` at all. `string.Replace(string, string)` do the search for you and replaces all occurrences in the string anyway. And if the searched string is not found it just returns the original string.

So your algorithm can be reduces to:

```
  foreach (Item item in items)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.ChildName.Replace(item.Name, "").Trim()} Car");
  }
```

---

> `string temp = string.Format("{0} {1}", item.ChildName, "Car");`

Why do you have the constant string `"Car"` as an argument to `Format` and not just as part of the format string itself.

---

> `new Item { Id = 1, Name = "Audi", ChildName = "Audi A3 Premium Plus Audi" }`

this will produce this output:

```
A3 Premium Plus  Car
```

(with an space char too many between "Plus" and "Car")

To fix it you must call `Trim()` on the returned string from `Replace()`:

```
string temp = string.Format("{0} {1}", item.ChildName.Replace(item.Name, "").Trim(), "Car");
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you use the returned value of `IndexOf()` only to check if it is `> -1` a more readable way would be to use `Contains()` instead of `IndexOf()`.

Internally `Contains()` does mostly the same than your comparison of the returned value. In the reference source of [`Contains()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/428c5c9954dea844.html) you will find

```
[Pure]
public bool Contains( string value ) {
    return ( IndexOf(value, StringComparison.Ordinal) >=0 );
}
```

while the counterpart of [`IndexOf()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/428c5c9954dea844.html) will look like so

```
[Pure]
public int IndexOf(String value) {
    return IndexOf(value, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
}
```

The difference between these two methods by the meaning of the internally called `IndexOf()` method is the passed [`StringComparison`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=netframework-4.8) parameter.

By reading the documentation you will read in the [remarks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) section

> When you call a string comparison method such as String.Compare,
>   String.Equals, or String.IndexOf, you should always call an overload
>   that includes a parameter of type StringComparison so that you can
>   specify the type of comparison that the method performs. For more
>   information, see Best Practices for Using Strings.

Let us check what that means by using the german word `daß` and compare the results from `StringComparison.CurrentCulture`, `StringComparison.InvariantCulture` and `StringComparison.Ordinal`

```
Console.WriteLine("daß".IndexOf("daß", StringComparison.Ordinal));
Console.WriteLine("daß".IndexOf("dass", StringComparison.Ordinal));
Console.WriteLine("daß".IndexOf("dass", StringComparison.CurrentCulture));
Console.WriteLine("daß".IndexOf("dass", StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
```

this will yield the results

> 0
>   -1
>   0
>   0

As you see you need to know what you want to get returned by calling `IndexOf()`. If you need to know if the **exact string** is contained inside another string you shouldn't use the default `IndexOf()` method.

Answer (score 3):

`Heslacher` and `Henrik Hansen` have given you good insights. In your case, `Replace` would be more appropriate to use as `Henrik Hansen` pointed out. The only addition that I would add is you can use `Linq` to do the same :

```
var result = items.Select(item => string.Format("{0} Car", item.ChildName.Replace(item.Name, string.Empty).Trim())).ToList();
```

and also `string.Join()` if you want it to concatenating the results. 
Example :

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", result));
```

the `\n` means new line. you can use any separator such as comma or space if you like.

Also, while I liked the `AlsoAdd` extension (thank you for this, I've now a new Idea to be implemented ;) ), I don't know why you re-doing what is already shipped with .NET! As you can do this :

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item { Id = 1, Name = "Audi", ChildName = "Audi A3 Premium Plus" },
    new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Audi", ChildName = "Audi A5 Premium Plus"},
    new Item { Id = 1, Name = "Audi", ChildName = "Audi A6 Premium Plus 55 TFSI quattro"},
    new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Audi", ChildName = "S5 Premium Plus 3.0 TFSI quattro"},
    new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Audi", ChildName = "S3 Premium Plus 3.0 TFSI quattro"}
};
```

which is a ready to use shortcut in .NET !

Hope this would be helpful.